# Sign of the integral of product even and odd symmetric function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $g(x)$ is odd symmetric around zero that is 
\begin{align}
g(x)=-g(-x)
\end{align}
also $g(x)\ge 0$ for $x>0$.

and $f(x)$ is positive and even symmetric around $x=a$.

How to show that 
\begin{align}
 {\rm sign} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)\cdot f(x) dx \right) ={\rm sign}(a)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.

Let $g = 1_{(0,1)}-1_{(-1,0)}$, $a=1$ and $f=1_{(-1,0)}+1_{(2,3)}$, then
$\int g f = -1$, but $\operatorname{sgn} a = +1$.

Comment: Is it true of if $g$ and $f$ are continuous?

Comment: No, you can see this by smoothing $f,g$ slightly, but the computation is more painful. Actually, you could adapt $\sin$ (gated by an indicator function) to obtain the same result in an analogous way.

Comment: Can we impose  a condition on $f$ and $g$ that would imply this?